# Java: Bug: JFileChooser only showing up sometimes

Tags: java, file, jfilechooser

I have  a method to open JFileChooser and allow to user to choose a file to later copy the URL of it. However, JFileChooser only shows up sometimes I run the program (?).

I do not understand what is wrong with the code. Thanks in advance.

> More clearly: The UI of the JFileChooser does not show up.

```
    String readThisGlos = null;

    JFrame parentFrame = new JFrame();
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Choose");
    int userSelection = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(parentFrame);
    if (userSelection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File fileToSave = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

        readThisGlos = fileToSave.getAbsolutePath();
    } else {
        // Error
    }
    System.out.println(readThisGlos);
    return readThisGlos;
```

Edit: I know the method is running, because when I put a `System.out.println("//something")`; in the beginning of the method, it works.

> If I put `System.out.println("//something");` between `fileChooser` and `int userSelection`, the UI shows up.

Comment: can you show some more code how you are calling this piece of code?

Comment: It's wrapped around  `public static String loadGlosFilManuell() {}`

Comment: do you get any issues/stacktrace on console while opening the file chooser

Comment: Why are you creating a parent frame? You can use `showOpenDialog(null)` if the parent frame is not an already existing frame.

Comment: @VivekSingh No. Nothing happens. I do really not understand why. The program keeps running without anything happening.

Comment: I tried you code at my end and it does not give me issues. For your case follow @RealSkeptic suggestion. Remove the frame part and provide the currently loaded from or just keep it as null.

Comment: @VivekSingh His suggestion did not change anything. I've restarted eclipse but this problem still exists. Refer to my latest edit. Isn't there any explanation to this? Is it just my computer that is weird?

Comment: I guess this is just an issue with your system. try and run your code on a different machine if you can.

Comment: Using a simple starting point like
    public static void main(String[] args) {
  loadGlosFilManuell();
    }
works?

Comment: I ran this. It works as it should for me. The problem may be somewhere else with your system.

Comment: Well, on my machine, if I use your code, the dialog doesn't show. If I use my suggestion (remove the `JFrame` and pass `null` to the `showOpenDialog`, the GUI is shown. Using an undisplayed `JFrame` is a recipe for trouble.

Comment: Debug your code by adding simple `System.out.println("Debug 1");` at some places to see that if something is blocking your program from running.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem once, I cannot even describe my frustration then.

Try this:

1. Restart computer
2. In eclipse: File --> Restart
3. Clean: C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin" -clean
4. Change `showOpenDialog(parentFrame)` to `showOpenDialog(null)` (as an user suggested, unnecessary things tend to create problems).
5. Run the program again.

Comment: YES!! Thanks so much!